# Google Chrome and Gmail shortcut

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Is anyone seeing a problem with Google Chrome Dev channel where Gmail application icons are bringing up a chrome window filled with javascript instead of Gmail?  When I say GMail application icon, I'm referring to the link you get in Start Menu/Desktop/QuickLaunch area when you choose "Create application shortcuts..." in chrome.

I'm on build 3.0.195.x.  I should also mention that other Google apps like Reader seem to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me on Dev channel version 3.0.195.4 on both my GMail account and my hosted Apps account.

Perhaps try deleting the shortcut and trying again?

Typically when I've seen Chrome act this way it's because the file was being sent from the server with an improper MIMEType.